# How to multiply multiple variables in a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming

I was trying to formulate a problem as an integer linear programming problem.

I have binary variables x[i] and y[i] for i in [1,n] that are constrained to have a value of 0 or 1.

I want to make the following constraint:
sum(x[i] * y[i] for i in array) <= 100

I want to be able to multiply the x[i] and y[i] together but then this becomes a quadratic equation (not linear).

Is there any way I could do this? I'm pretty new to linear programming so I would really appreciate any help!!

Comment: in which programming language will you implement the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a bit of theory. We can linearize

```
z = x*y
```

for **binary variables** *x,y,z* by:

```
z <= x
z <= y
z >= x+y-1
```

In your specific case, we can apply this as follows:

```
sum(i, z[i]) <= 100 
z[i] >= x[i] + y[i] - 1
```

where `z[i]` is an extra binary variable. We don't need the <= constraints `z[i] <= x[i], z[i] <= y[i]`. We can relax `z[i]` to be continuous between 0 and 1 which sometimes can help a bit in performance.

Note that the presence of binary variables no longer makes this an LP, but rather this is a MIP model.